# Physical device not sending data to Firebasedatabase

Tags: iphone, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter app sends/stores data to Firestore perfectly on iOS and Android emulators, but it can't send or store data using the `physical device` `(ios)`.

I don't know much about Android physical devices because I don't have an Android device at the moment.

Any help?

```
void signInWithPhone(
    BuildContext context,
    String phoneNumber,
  ) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted:
              (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
          },
          verificationFailed: (error) {
            throw Exception(error.message);//ERROR directs me to this line
          },
          codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    OTPScreen(verificationId: verificationId),
              ),
            );
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {});
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      //do something
    }
  }


void sendPhoneNumber() async {
    // final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    String phoneNumber = phone.text.trim();

    signInWithPhone(
      context,
      "+7$phoneNumber",
    );
  }


MaterialButton(
onPressed: (){
sendPhoneNumber();
}
)


ERROR: _RegistrationState.signInWithPhone.<anonymous closure> // the error directs me to this line in the code
throw Exception(error.message);
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague and a little confusing. It states you can't send data using the physical device (ios). But then references Android devices? Also, it states - *can't send or store data* - is there an error? Are you using the Firebase emulator at all or just the device via XCode? Have you done any troubleshooting to see what specific piece of code is not working? Please update and clarify the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: What I meant was that I have only iphone so I've not tried android. But the problem might be the same for android as well, that's why I referenced Android device.

Comment: With not being able to send or store data, I meant using the physical device. I have to problem with emulators. They work well

Comment: The issue is how the function is being called, and shown by the error: `ERROR: _RegistrationState.signInWithPhone.<anonymous closure>` with this `anonymous closure` being something to do a bit of research on.